# Missing SQL Server Data Tools on WIndows 8

Tags: windows-8, sql-server-data-tools

I installed SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe on my Windows 8 PC, which already had Visual Studio.

How Do I start the data tools, I don't see a start icon or find it in the windows 8 menus.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Data Tools will install into a Visual Studio instance. You can create new SSIS, Database, SSRS, or SSAS projects within Visual Studio, depending on what components of SSDT you installed.

Comment: So How do I get the the project screen of SSIS.

Comment: File - New Project.  SSIS would be under the BI section, if I remember correctly.  Database projects are under the "SQL" type, I think.